# Selecting subset of separate bands in GRASS GIS?

Tags: grass-gis

As you know landsat data has separate files for different bands. Creating a
subset is a wise option to work on region of our interest. Therefore, I used
this method to subset my image -

```
d.zoom || g.region
g.region -p
r.mapcalc *subset*=original
```

But with this I can subset one band data at a time. Is it somehow possible
to use i.group and region definition to obtain subsets of all bands? Scripting might be an answer but I have no much idea about it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create a subset with r.mapcalc.
Since you set a region with g.region any calculations made to the data will use only the portion of the images that fall within the region extents.

Answer (score 2):

The above question fits to be a generic automation question, like *how to repeat task T over several maps M?*.

If you do work on Linux (with a [bash-shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash) beforehand), you can utilise bash shell command line utilities (read also [Shell Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Commands.html#Shell-Commands)).  Among the most frequently used is the `for` loop[(ing construct)](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs).  A simple example could be (where *MAP* is a variable which "contains" in each loop one of the requested maps *MAP_A*, *MAP_B*, *MAP_C*):

```
for MAP in MAP_A MAP_B MAP_C ; do r.mapcalc "${MAP}"_subset = "${MAP}" ; done
```

The above command will execute `r.mapcalc "${MAP}"_subset = "${MAP}"` over the 3 maps *MAP_A*, *MAP_B*, *MAP_C*.

Of course one can feed the loop with as many maps -- let them be vector or raster -- as asked!  Another example, within GRASS-GIS' environment, could be using the results of a `g.list` command to feed the `$MAP` variable (given there are raster maps named with the prefix "landsat_"):

```
for MAP in `g.list rast=landsat*` ; do r.mapcalc "${MAP}"_subset = "${MAP}" ; done
```

The above command will repeat the same as above command over all maps whose name begins with the prefix *landsat_*.

An on-going effort to enrich the respective GRASS-GIS wikipage with simple examples is located at [GRASS and Shell](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Shell)

Comment: Will "enable" hyperlinks when required reputation will be collected.

Comment: Hyperlinks enabled--thanks to the voter for this answer! Although it was an "old" question, I consider it as a valid one.